# A recommendation for a book about branching processes

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

I am a PhD math student looking for a good book for studying branching processes (AKA Galton - Watson processes).
Any suggestions?

Comment: Lyons and Peres, "Probability on Trees and Networks".

Comment: @Did thank you, this looks like a good source. I will be happy to get some more suggestions though.